# how do i make an object in gamemaker only overlap on one side?

Tags: game-mechanics, browser-based-games

I am making a small flash game in game maker 8.0 pro and I need some help. In my game, the character is in an office with cubicles. I need my character to be able to walk behind and in front of the cubicles with the correct overlapping for each scenario. Here are some pics. As you can see walking up to the wall from the back looks fine but it over laps the same way walking up to the wall from the wall from the front which is a problem. If anyone could help me with this problem that'd be great. Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmRKV.png)

[image]

edit: i resolved my issue. It turns out you can use any objects position on the y axis to set its depth with: depth=-y
you might have to adjust it slightly to account for collision masks like this:
depth=-y-32

Comment: You have a better chance of being answered at the game maker people's space than here.